# Is there any SAST tool which supports Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina, sast

I am verifying the possibility for switching to Ballerina as a new strategy for our current wso2 solution. There are several pro's and con's. One major concern that I have is the lack of SAST support. Is someone able to confirm this concern or did I overlooked something?

Comment: As of now, Ballerina does not have SAST support.